# Application of Schwarz Proposition to prove inequality

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be holomorphic on $B(0,1)$, $f(0)=1$,  and $Ref(z)$ non-negative everywhere in the ball. Show that:

(1) $\frac {1-|z|} {1+|z|}\le Ref(z)\le |f(z)|\le \frac {1+|z|} {1-|z|}$ holds everywhere in the ball;

(2) The equivalence holds for some $|z|>0$, if and only if $f(z)=\frac {1+e^{it}z} {1-e^{it}z}$, where $t\in \mathbb {R}$.

---

I have proved the right part of the inequality using Schwarz's Proposition.

Let $g=\frac {f-1} {f+1}$, then by Schwarz's Proposition, $|g(z)|\le |z|$. Then simple calculation tells $|f(z)|\le \frac {1+|z|} {1-|z|}$.
But I am stuck how to address the left part with regard to $Ref(z)$?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Let $h(z)=\dfrac{1}{f(z)}$ then $h(0)=1$ and ${\bf Re}\,h(z)>0$ also, so you can apply your method.

Comment: Thank you very much. By $g=1/f$ I get $LHS≤|f(z)|$. And I know that $Ref(z)≤|f(z)|$. But why $LHS≤Ref(z)$?

Answer (score 2):

We want to prove that
(1) $\frac {1-|z|} {1+|z|}\le \operatorname{Re}f(z)$ holds everywhere in the ball;
(2) The equivalence $\frac {1-|z|} {1+|z|}= \operatorname{Re}f(z)$ holds for some $|z|>0$, if and only if $f(z)=\frac {1+e^{it}z} {1-e^{it}z}, t\in\mathbb{R}.$

Let $\varphi (z)=\frac{1+z}{1-z}$. Then $$g(z)=\frac{f(z)-1}{f(z)+1}=\left(\varphi ^{-1}\circ f\right)(z)$$ and we have already proven $$|g(z)|\le |z|.\tag{1}$$

Let $D_r=\{z:|z|<r\}$, $r\le 1$. Then $(1)$ means that $$g(D_r)=\left(\varphi ^{-1}\circ f\right)(D_r)\subset D_r,$$
since $|g(z)|<r$ holds for all $z$ with $|z|<r.$ Now from $\left(\varphi ^{-1}\circ f\right)(D_r)\subset D_r$ we have $$
f(D_r)\subset \varphi (D_r).$$

Note that $$\varphi (D_r)=\left\{z:\left|z-\frac{1+r^2}{1-r^2}\right|<\frac{2r}{1-r^2}\right\},$$ i.e. $\varphi $ maps $D_r$ onto a disk centered at $z=\frac{1+r^2}{1-r^2}$ with radius $\frac{2r}{1-r^2}$. Therefore $f(D_r)\subset \varphi (D_r)$ implies $$
\frac{1-r}{1+r}< \operatorname{Re}f(z),\, (|z|<r).$$
This leads to 
$$
\frac{1-|z|}{1+|z|}\le  \operatorname{Re}f(z).$$

(2). \begin{align}
&f(z)\ne \frac {1+e^{it}z} {1-e^{it}z}\implies g(z)\ne e^{it}z\\
&\implies |g(z)|<r \text{ for all } |z|=r>0\text{ (by Schwarz lemma)}\\
&\implies \frac{1-r}{1+r}<\operatorname{Re}f(z)\text{ for all }|z|=r>0.
\end{align}
Therefore if $\frac {1-|z|} {1+|z|}= \operatorname{Re}f(z)$ holds for some $|z|>0$, $f$ must be $\frac {1+e^{it}z} {1-e^{it}z}.$